# How to display parsed json?

Tags: javascript, json

I would like to display parsed JSON on my own page (with possibility to collapse sections). I found chrome extension with open source json viewer - https://code.google.com/p/chrome-rest-client/source/browse/trunk/RestClient/war/workers/jsonviewer.js?r=148, but I don't understand how to use it. 
I've created section for json display -

```
<div class="json-viewer" id="jsonViewer">
</div>
```

and try to display it there with the following code:

```
var json='{"q":"iphone","r":["iphone 5","iphone","обмен на iphone","iphone 4","iphone 5s"]}';
$("#jsonViewer").html(JSONViewer(json));
```

but it shows just nothing.

Answer (score 0):

The function `JSONViewer` is a constructor function. You must instantiate an `JSONViewer`object first before you can use it:

```
var json='{"q":"iphone","r":["iphone 5","iphone","обмен на iphone","iphone 4","iphone 5s"]}',
jsonParser = new JSONViewer(json);
$("#jsonViewer").html(jsonParser.getHTML());
```

This is a working plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/Rfmm1QSDcc1CPxy9a2HT?p=preview

Comment: Thanks, Nikolas. But with such code it just formats the JSON. Originally it allows to collapse the elements.